# Which armour would be more beneficial when farming the Moon Lord?

Tags: terraria

I am going to be farming the Moon Lord using the weapon *Razer Blade Typhoon*. I am unsure what is the best armor to pair it with for the most efficient farming patterns. Is it better to use **Spectre** armor for better survival through life steal, or **Nebula** for the extra stats all around?

Answer (score 3):

The question as worded is opinion based. You might want to ask what armor set gives most damage or something similar.

However, Spectre armor does not benefit from life steal against the moon lord because of his [moon bite debuff](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Moon_Bite). This would make it effectively 40% reduced damage and no healing which is next to useless.